# How to bind attributes of dynamically added element to its parent's attribute value in Angulrjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-material

I have a model (angular material autocomplete element) used across various pages of my application, this autocomplete does not have a clear button so I made a directive which dynamically add a close button when this autocomplete has same value and remove it when there is no value in autocomplete.
my requirement is to disable this close button when model's(auto complete) ng-disabled gets evaluated to true.
I know there are various ways of doing this specially using isolate scope and binding their values, but I do not want to modify all of my already developed pages.

[CodePen link](http://codepen.io/sohail85/pen/GjmOPw)

```
function clearAutocomplete($parse, $compile, $log) {
  var diretive = {    
    restrict: 'A',
    link: linkFunciton
  }
  return diretive;

  function linkFunciton(scope, element, attrs) {
    var ngDisabledModel = $parse(attrs.ngDisabled);
    scope.isDisabled = ngDisabledModel(scope);// value binded to auto complete ng-diabled

    var button = angular.element('<md-button>').attr('ng-disabled', '{{isDisabled}}');

    button.append('<md-icon md-font-set="material-icons">close</md-icon>');
    element.append(button);

    $compile(button)(scope); 

    var searchTextModel = $parse(attrs.mdSearchText);
    scope.$watch(ngDisabledModel, function(isElementDisabled) {
      scope.isDisabled = isElementDisabled;
    });

    button.on('click', function() {
        scope.$apply(function() {
            searchTextModel.assign(scope, undefined);
            element.find('input').focus();
        });
    });
  }
}
```

The problem with this code is even if the autocomplete gets disabled the clear button remains enabled.
what is the best way to achieve this functionality(without adding any isolated scope)

Answer (score 0):

Replace your button with this:

`<md-icon md-font-set="material-icons" ng-disabled="isDisabled">close</md-icon>`

This will disable the close button whenever your isDisabled variable is flipped to true in the watcher.